# Postgres disable super user account

Tags: postgresql

How does one go about disabling a super user account within postgres without deleting it.  I looked at the Alter Role documentation and I am drawing blanks.  In addition this is the only super user account and the subordinate accounts own the tables that they are responsible for

Comment: Why would you want to do that? The use `postgres` can't be disabled.

Comment: @jmz its necessary for a security requirement

Comment: I don't see how that increases security. You might succeed in using a different name though, perhaps the name you use to connect to the DB. Drop your cluster, deluser postgres, create the user you want as a Unix user, initdb with that user. The user is now ID=1 and is the only superuser. It works just like the postgres user was. So you're at square one. The point is that you need the automatically generated user and the postgres account (or some other). You could just as well use the postgres account to connect.

Comment: @jmz please tell me there is some white paper explaining this as well so that I may present it.

Comment: Woot4Moo: Read http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/creating-cluster.html for security hints.

Comment: I would like to mention that I don't think this is a programming question and should have been posted on SF.

Comment: @xenoterracide In all reality it is a programming question, unless of course you don't count SQL as a programming language (of sorts)

Comment: I consider this to be a systems administration problem. configuring a .conf file is not programming or sql. Also I feel that SQL and other DBA stuff is quite different from other Programming which is why I'm in favor of [this stack exchange proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4260/outer-join?referrer=A71RjNgv6G65LIh8JGLLjA2)

Comment: fair enough sdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could configure `pg_hba.conf` to reject the super user so it can't log in.

Comment: Indeed. Disabling login would effectively disable the account. Also seems to be the pattern Linux and some Windows installations follow.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you have created a new user with  super user privileges and you don't want to disable the postgres account, right?

To disable an account try revoke:

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES
ON DATABASE mydb
FROM mysuperuser;
```

I might have missed something in the snippet above, check out the docs here:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-revoke.html

To remove the user, become super user yourself, ie postgres. Then use DROP ROLE:

```
DROP ROLE mysuperuser;
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/sql-droprole.html

Answer (score 1):

There is always a superuser, you  can't maintain your database without this role.

Comment: Any documents to validate this?

Comment: Just check the manual, many statements need a superuser (CREATE LANGUAGE is one of them) and you need a superuser to create a superuser role. Without a superuser, you're on a dead end street.

Comment: Thanks.  So logically my argument is going to be that a non super user does not have the necessary rights to grant privileges back to my super user in the case of maintenance